# How can I specify a mainClass in build.sbt that resides in another module?

Tags: scala, build, sbt

For some reason, our project got reorganized with the main class thrown in another *module*

I've specified the `mainClass` as below in the build.sbt but I still get a class not found error:

`mainClass in Compile := Some("com.so.questions.sbt.Main")`

However, this is bound to fail since it's going to look for the Main class in the `src` folder. However, this module lives outside of (sibling of) `src`:

```
MyScalaProject
+-MyModule
|+-src
| +-com.so.questions.sbt
|  +-Main
|+-build.sbt <-- build.sbt specific to this module, currently blank
+-src
| +-<other folders>
+-build.sbt  <-- build.sbt currently housing all config
```

How can I change the project scope in `build.sbt` to find and correctly load the main class?

That is, is it possible to do `sbt run` at the top level and have the main class be found with this structure?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you have the `MyModule` module/folder containing the main class and some other module called `MyCoreModule` (just to illustrate the whole build.sbt):

```
// any stuff that you want to share between modules
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
    scalaVersion  := "2.12.8",
    version       := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    name := "parent-module"
  )
  .aggregate(core, app)
  .dependsOn(app) // <-- here is the config that will allow you to run "sbt run" from the root project

lazy val core = project.in(file("MyCoreModule"))
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    name := "core"
  )

lazy val app = project.in(file("MyModule"))
  .dependsOn(core)
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    name := "app"
    )

// define your mainClass from the "app" module
mainClass in Compile := (mainClass in Compile in app).value
```

Btw, `sbt.version=1.2.7`

Answer (score 0):

It should work.

The FQCN specification for `mainClass` should be location independent to my understanding.

The real question that comes to mind is how you are loading your sub-module.
Here are some sbt definitions that should help point you in the right direction ( replace the `<>` tags with your own project Ids) :

```
// Define a submodule ref to be able to include it as a dependency
lazy val subModuleRef = ProjectRef(file("MyModule"),<MyModule SBT NAME>)

// Define a submodule project to be able to orchestrate it's build 
lazy val subModule = Project(
  id = <MyModule SBT NAME>,
  base = file("MyModule"),
).addSbtFiles(file("build.sbt"))

// Define the top-level project, depending and subModule Ref for code
// inclusion and aggregating the subModule for build orchestration
lazy val scalaProject = Project(
  id = <MyScalaProject NAME>,
  base = file("."),
  aggregate = Seq(subModule),
  settings = commonSettings
).dependsOn(subModuleRef).
```